# Make Browser App Available As Default Browser

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store

I recently developed a mobile app for both Android and IOS which is a full featured web browser. I was wondering how to make the app be available as a default browser which can be selected from the users settings.

Here is an image of what I’m looking for:
[image]

Comment: For iOS https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/preparing-your-app-to-be-the-default-browser-or-email-client

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.